# How to do a location regex match for nginx that matches prefix with no extra slashes

Tags: nginx, location

I want to create a location regex match in nginx that allows routes starting with `/subscriptions[optional shash /][...anything...]` as unless additional slashes are found later in the path.

```
/subscriptions/000000       OK
/subscriptions              OK
/subscriptions/             OK
/subscriptions/dasddsad/    NOT OK
/subscriptions/             NOT OK
```

the reason is that I have other regex matches that also matches those cases where additional slashes are present, so when it hits any of the NOT OK above, it shuold just continue to other location checks.

Comment: Why not order the other regular expressions first. `nginx` uses the first regular expression that matches. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Comment: i have them ordered, but was just not getting my regex correct. Found a working regex: ~* ^/subscriptions/?[^/]*$